# PDO - check if row was updated?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Other people have asked this question, but mine is a little more specific.

I have this query:

```
$sql = "UPDATE table SET option=? WHERE number=?";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($option, $number));
$q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);

echo $q->rowCount();
```

If the WHERE `number` already exists and the SET `option` is same, `$q->rowCount()` equals `0`

If the WHERE `number` doesnt exist and the row does not update, `$q->rowCount()` equals `0`

How can I distinguish between these non-updates?

Comment: Why do you need to distinguish between them?

Comment: Because if the row does not exist, then I would like to insert it in a 2nd query.

Comment: to create it with the known `id` value?

Comment: yes, its not actually the id column. i used "id" to simplify the example. Its really just another column in the table. I updated the example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On recent PHP versions, it's controlled by the `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS` attribute.
When set to `true`, according to the [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php), the effect is:

> ```
> Return the number of found (matched) rows, not the number of changed rows.
> ```

Comment: But this has to be done on DB connect, right?
So you still cannot differentiate between these at the same time, at least using this method.
It would be great if you could do: `$q->exe(); $q->rowsChanged(); $q->rowsFound();` But it is just not even close to that easy.

Comment: Be sure to also check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17501997/can-pdo-rowcount-after-update-query-show-difference-between-no-changes-made

Answer (score 1):

Will be better check before if exists? I use a common function for this in my miniclass for manage PDO, but i dont know if is the best solution because make one query more...

```
function checkExistsInDatabase($id, $table, $where = null){

    // Connect
    $Database = Database::connect();

    // Query
    $sql = "SELECT id 
            FROM $table
            WHERE id = :id $where
            LIMIT 1";
    $params = array(
                ':id' => array(
                    'value' => $id,
                    'type' => 'int'
                )
              );
    $q = $Database->query($sql, $params);

    // Ha encontrado algo?
    $resultados = $Database->fetchArray($q);
    if(count($resultados) === 1){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try using [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/replace.html) which work's like insert but if the row already exists its first deleted and then inserted. This has overwork from mysql side

Comment: with `REPLACE` you would lose all the other columns values

Comment: you can specify the values in the `REPLACE` to keep the values, you need to use them in the `INSERT` statement anyway

Comment: which values? How do you know currently existing ones?

Comment: the same way you obtain them to do the `INSERT` statement?

Comment: for insert you use initial values, and you don't know what values are currently in the row

Answer (score -1):

**Add this:**

```
$db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS => true));
```

**to the first "try {" part of your databasefunctions.php file**