# Can PDO rowCount() after UPDATE query show difference between "no changes made" and "unexisting row"?

Tags: mysql, pdo

I'm doing an update query with PDO. I would like to figure out if my update query did not change anything in the database, since:

1. the passed values are the same as already present in the database. I know that `rowCount()` in such a case returns `0`.
2. the row I'm trying to update does not exist in the database. As far as I can see, `rowCount()`in such cases also returns `0`.

Am I forced to precede my UPDATE by a SELECT statement, to figure out if the record I'm trying to update does in fact exist? Or is there another common practice for this sort of thing.

I've been perusing through the documentation, but cannot find a conclusive answer:
http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

I've come across this StackOverflow answer, that suggests that rowCount() might return NULL in some scenario's, but I don't think it's apliccable to my scenario:
see [Why does PDO rowCount() return 0 after UPDATE a table without modifying the existing data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237212/why-does-pdo-rowcount-return-0-after-update-a-table-without-modifying-the-exis)

From the comments in this question:

> If the data hasn't been modified, the rowCount will be zero. If the
>   data was modified, the rowCount will be one or higher. If there was an
>   error, rowCount will be null or false or something non-zero.

**UPDATE**
I've found another question that gives an example of the proposition in the comments below:
[Getting the insert and update ID with PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106555/getting-the-insert-and-update-id-with-pdo)

**UPDATE2**
Another question proposes another solution, via `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS`
[PDO - check if row was updated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10728811/pdo-check-if-row-was-updated?rq=1)

Comment: No, as far as I know. If you *really* need that number, you can `SELECT ... FRO UPDATE` first. The question has nothing to do with PDO, by the way.

Comment: If there is an ID in the table, then you can add `id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id)` to your update clause. This way, `PDO::lastInsertId` will return you a number.

Comment: Thanks, I will investigate later today and get back to you. Seems like a very nice functionality.

Comment: @hjpotter92 I am afraid you completely missed the point

Comment: @hjpotter92 Could you elaborate on your suggestion please? I don't really understand how I would implement your solution.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I am using MyIsam. Is `SELECT FOR UPDATE` still a suitable solution in this case? I read that MyIsam does not support row level locking.

Comment: it can lock entire table though.

Comment: Thanks, but I think this would be not suitable in my case, as several users will be inserting, updating and deleting at the same time. I'm investigating the solution presented by @hjpotter92, if that fails, is a simple select before my update the right way to go?

Comment: Yes, this latter one seems the solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PDO - check if row was updated?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10728811/pdo-check-if-row-was-updated)

Comment: @hjpotter92, I've used your suggestions to construct a solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it using the suggestions of @hjpotter92.

```php
// UID is the unique ID of my table, autoincremented etc...
// Firstly, let's try to update my row
$query = 'UPDATE my_table SET x=0, y=1, uid=LAST_INSERT_ID(uid) WHERE z=2';
$sth = $dbh->prepare($query);
if($sth->execute()) {
    if($dbh->lastInsertId() == 0) { // Record was not found, so insert it.
        $query = 'INSERT INTO my_table (x,y) VALUES (0,1)';
        $sth = $dbh->prepare($query);
        $sth->execute();
        if($sth->rowCount() > 0) {
            echo $dbh->lastInsertId(); // Return the UID of the inserted row
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add conditionals to your 'where' clause so such as " and ColumnToUpdate <> 'NewValue'"