# How can I make rowCount return 1 and not 0?

Tags: sql, pdo, rowcount

I know that if I try to make an update using PDO and the affected rows are 0, then rowCount returns 0.

As I'm working on a new administration panel I was wondering how can I fix this because somebody ( the administrator ) can try to save something and for me rowCount 0 means no update in database and for this I'm showing an error.

I'm thinking. Can be some error for an Update and return 0 at rowCount unless if there ware 0 affected rows ? Because if not, then the next verification should fix my problem.

```
if($q->rowCount() == 0 || $q->rowCount() == 1) { show success message }
```

So is this a good practice ? Any advice please ?

Thank you and sorry for my language.

Comment: seems close to that one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17501997/can-pdo-rowcount-after-update-query-show-difference-between-no-changes-made

Answer (score 0):

PDO implements methods that return error information.

Depending on what you're trying to do, you should look at

- [PDO::errorCode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorcode.php), or
- [PDOStatement::errorCode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorcode.php)